# How to get the page access token in facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating my first app in facebook. In that i am trying to access the user's page account details. I used this code:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
          if (response.status === 'connected') {
            alert('connected');
            var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            getusername();              

}
```

Here i can able to get the user's main account id ,access_token, name everything. For getting the user's page account details i used this code

```
function getusername(){
    FB.api('/me/accounts', function(response){
            var p_accessToken = response.accessToken;
            var p_name = response.name;
            alert('The pagename is:'+ p_name + 'Page access token is' + p_accessToken);

        });
```

But it alerted the name and access_token as undefined. I dont know how to access the name, access_token of the page.

I think I need to change this p_accessToken =response.accessToken line.

But i dont know how to get this. Can anyone help me .

Comment: Have you asked for Page permission?

Comment: No. How i can get the permission. I think I have to get permission using manage pages. But i dont know how to use that. Can u help me @Anvesh Saxena

Comment: `FB.login(function(){//Call back function to do things like checking if user logged in or not},"scope":"manage_pages")`

Comment: FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            testAPI();
        } else {
            // cancelled
        }
    }, "scope":"manage_pages"); i gave like this it is giving syntax error

Comment: Sorry, error on my part. Instead of `"scope":"manage_pages"` please write `{"scope":"manage_pages"}` also check [FB.login](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/)

Comment: I added that line. Still it is coming as undefined.

Comment: Thanks. It is coming now @Anvesh Saxena

Comment: I have also added a sample code in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25830/discussion-between-priya-sunanthan-and-anvesh-saxena)

Comment: You can follow the details steps as explained here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76329303/12326605

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an issue with your code, I have corrected it

```
<script> 
FB.login(function(response){ 
FB.api('/me/accounts', function(response){ 
   var p_accessToken = response.data[0].access_token; 
   var p_name = response.data[0].name; 
   alert('The pagename is:'
           + p_name + 'Page access token is' 
           + p_accessToken);});}
   ,{scope:"manage_pages"}); 
</script>
```

the data is an array with your accounts being on different index numbers
also its access_token instead of accessToken